# Pytorch Geometric gives me an 'edge_index' error

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, pytorch-geometric, graph-neural-network

I am trying to use Pytorch Geometric on my own custom Dataset. However I keep getting this error "Please ensure that all indices in 'edge_index' point to valid indices in the interval [0, 13) in your node feature matrix and try again."

I checked that the max of edge_index is not greater than the number of nodes. Can anyone explain whats happening?

I have tried redoing my adjacency and edge_index matrices and I don't have this problem on InMemory datasets. Since I am making my own dataset, I see this error!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.